# Showing FragmentDialogs below each other

Tags: android

Default behaviour is to show each new dialog on top of currently visible dialogs. If I use .show() method:

```
dialog0.show(fragmentManager, null)
dialog1.show(fragmentManager, null)
```

Then I will end up seeing dialog1.

Is there a way to change that and show new dialogs below those dialogs that are already shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to change that and show new dialogs below those dialogs that are already shown?

No, not with system Dialog. If you need such feature (still I think if you do then something seems wrong with your UX) then you need to have complete custom solution, i.e. another activity styled as dialog and then layout all you want as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Cascading dialogs is not the right way. Instead try to do something like this:

```
final Queue<AlertDialog> dialogQueue = new LinkedList<>();
[...]

AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
alert.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
alert.setMessage(R.string.dialog_msg);
alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int which) {

        AlertDialog next = dialogQueue.poll();
        if(next != null){
            next.show();
        }

    }
});

alert.show();
```